# Sieves in arithmetic geometry

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, sieve-theory

What are some good resources to learn more about applications of sieve methods in arithmetic geometry?

There are some applications of sieve methods to function fields in the notes of Zeev Rudnick that I found [here](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html) as well as [these](https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2014/2014PoonenNotes.pdf) notes by Bjorn Poonen from the Arizona Winter School.

Are there any books which specifically deal with sieve methods for function fields, or more generally, applications of sieve methods in arithmetic geometry?